# Плавное появление меню - свойство transition

Tags: html, css, css3

При добавлении свойства `transition` селектору `.menu`, ничего не выходит:

```css
#menu-toggle {
  display: none;
}

.menu {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.hamburger-menu {
  position: relative;
}

.hamburger-menu__menu-btn {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: -44px;
  right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.8;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0 #4a4646, -1px -1px 5px 0 #4a4646;
}

.hamburger-menu__hamburger,
.hamburger-menu__hamburger:before,
.hamburger-menu__hamburger:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 4px;
  background: #4a4646;
  transition: .3s;
}

.hamburger-menu__hamburger:before {
  content: '';
  top: -7px;
}

.hamburger-menu__hamburger:after {
  content: '';
  top: 7px;
}

#menu-toggle:checked~.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.menu__item_margin-left {
  margin-left: 0;
}

#menu-toggle:checked~.hamburger-menu__menu-btn>.hamburger-menu__hamburger:before {
  top: 0;
}

#menu-toggle:checked~.hamburger-menu__menu-btn>.hamburger-menu__hamburger:after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#menu-toggle:checked~.hamburger-menu__menu-btn>.hamburger-menu__hamburger {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="hamburger-menu">
  <input type="checkbox" name="menu-toggle" id="menu-toggle">
  <label class="hamburger-menu__menu-btn" for="menu-toggle">
    <span class="hamburger-menu__hamburger"></span>
  </label>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu__item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item menu__item_margin-left"><a href="#">About us</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item menu__item_margin-left"><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item menu__item_margin-left"><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item menu__item_margin-left"><a href="#">Employers</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item menu__item_margin-left"><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы меню появлялось плавно?

Comment: `transition` не работает для `display: block;`. можно пробовать через `max-height`

Answer (score 3):

Не уверен, что для выполнения перехода достаточно указать только время выполнения, как у вас в коде
обычно это выглядит вот так

```
transition: top 1s ease-out .5s
```